# JSLint Error: Expected an operator instead saw '{a}'

Tags: jslint

In my project ,we have the following condition which gets evaluated by JSLint

```
if(${Name} === 'SAM'){
Result = 1000;
return;
}
```

When I debug the code I am getting "Expected an operator but instead saw '{a}' " error at '{' character in if condition.Could you please help to rectify this?

Is if({XYZ}) allowed in JSLint

Comment: Is that even Javascript? Is there some sort of template engine we're not seeing or something? Did you mean to use parentheses instead of braces? `${Name}` doesn't look like Javascript to me.

Comment: `${Name}` is not valid JavaScript, so no, it is not allowed.

Comment: user2357112 might as well make that comment an answer; it's the right one.